pnpm not installing everything into my node_modules folder
I am trying to build a dev version of directus inside of a docker container (I have python issues with running it outside of a container).
This is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /directus

ARG TARGETPLATFORM

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

RUN <<EOF
  if [ "$TARGETPLATFORM" = 'linux/arm64' ]; then
    apk --no-cache add python3 build-base
    ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
  fi
EOF

COPY package.json .
RUN corepack enable && corepack prepare

COPY pnpm-lock.yaml .
RUN pnpm fetch

COPY . .
RUN pnpm install --recursive --force

This all seems to be OK (everything looks like it runs, and installs).
But, when I try to run my container using:
version: "3"
services:
  directus:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: "pnpm --recursive dev"
    ports:
      - "8055:8055"
    volumes:
      - .:/directus/
    depends_on:
      - cache
      - database

I get the error:
 Scope: 41 of 42 workspace projects
directus-directus-1  | packages/specs dev$ npm-watch build
directus-directus-1  | packages/specs dev: command not found: npm-watch
directus-directus-1  | packages/specs dev: Failed
directus-directus-1  | /directus/packages/specs:
directus-directus-1  |  ERR_PNPM_RECURSIVE_RUN_FIRST_FAIL  @directus/specs@10.2.8 dev: `npm-watch build`

And indeed, if I check my node_modules folder only the dependencies of my package.json are in there, and none of the other modules.
Isn't pnpm normally used to install everything inside of 1 node_modules folder? What am I missing here?
Thank you
